# getting error on executing a program LNK1104

Tags: visual-c++

i am using GLUT 3.7.6 with VC++6.0 n on compiling a program i get following error
--------------------Configuration: abc2 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "abc2.exe"
Error executing link.exe.

abc2.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

---

i have included all the header files ...linked all the lib files bt still the result is same...!!...please guide me through this problem...THNX in advance...!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1104](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031285/fatal-error-lnk1104)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the output file already exists and something has a lock on it. Check to see if abc2.exe is alright running, or of some program has a file lock on it.

Comment: Handle.exe from Sysinternals may come in handy for determining whether another program has abc2.exe locked: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether abc.exe is running using [Process Explorer from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). If that's the case the link step will fail.

Also check the target file is not write-protected.

All the Microsoft tool error codes are documented online - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more reasons why you might see LNK1104.